# Type interface com.smart.dao.UserDao is not known to the MapperRegistry

Tags: java, mybatis

1. This is my `mybatis.xml`:

   ```
   <mappers>
       <!--注册方式1，一个一个的配置-->
       <!--<mapper resource="mapper/UserMapper.xml"/>-->
       <!--注册方式2，自动包内的mapper接口与配置文件-->
       <package name="mapper"/>
   </mappers>
   ```
2. This is my `mapper.xml`:

   ```
   <mapper namespace="com.smart.dao.UserDao">
     <select id="selectUserById" resultType="com.smart.domain.User">
       SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE id = #{id}
     </select>
   </mapper>
   ```

Comment: Cool. What's your question? Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris，sorry，I put more infomation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016580/type-interface-com-smart-dao-userdao-is-not-known-to-the-mapperregistry-when-i

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide full reference to mybatis mapper. You can do that either by specifying the mapper resource completely. Or using the mybatis scanning feature.

If UserMapper.xml is in src/main/resources/*com/smart/dao/mapper* ()it'll be something like :

```
 <mybatis:scan base-package="com.smart.dao.mapper" />
```

Full doc and other options given here: http://www.mybatis.org/spring/mappers.html

Comment: I just only use mybatis,and do not use spring or others.I'am a new person

Comment: The logic is essentially the same even if you're not using spring. You can try registering the mappers using any of these configurations : 
http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#mappers
Currently the pacakge name `mapper` seems to be incorrect, you'll have to give the full package name,